# Using GMP to calculate very large Integers from formulas

Tags: c, gmp, outofrangeexception

I was having a hard time to figure out how to deal with a problem I encountered. 
As a part of a complex formula, I need to calculate a part that quickly overflows double, i.e. results get up to ~ 1.59*10^(1331) (calculated with mathematica).
Of course this is out of the range of double. Then I was thinking of using long double, which on my linux system with `gcc 4.6.3` is 16byte.

1) double precision (8byte) has a possible range of up to 10^(308). Am I right in saying, that long double then increases the actual precision, but not the possible numeric range of values? I remember that I heard that it can be either or,  depending on the system and the compiler. Is that true ? At least I still get NaN when I try to calculate my values with long double.

2.) I was then looking for a way to actually calculate these results and I found the GNU `gmp`. I heard that you can represent very large integers and I thought this might help. However, reading the documentation, it seems that with

```
 mpz_t x;
 mpz_init(x);
 mpz_set_*(x,#);
```

I can assign values to `gmp` integer data types, but in order to do that, I can "only" choose to assign values that can be represented by built-in data types like double or (u/s)int etc. All I found for how to assign really huge numbers was to use `mpz_set_str()` to assign the number from a string. 
How would I assign a number that is the result of a complex calculation ?
Simply speaking, formulas look like this:

```
long double res1,res2=0.0;
int a,b;
a=780;
b=741;
float d,d1,o,s; // can be values in [0.01,100]

res1=(2*(pow(b,2)*pow(E,b*(o + s))*(pow(d1,2) + pow(E,a*s)*(-1 + pow(E,a*o)) + pow(d,2)*(-1 + pow(E,a*s))) + pow(a,2)*pow(E,a*(o + s))*(pow(E,b*s)*(pow(E,b*o) + (-1 + d)*(1 + d + b*o)) + (-d + d1)*(d + d1 + b*o + b*d*s)) - a*b*(pow(d1,2)*(pow(E,a*(o + s)) + pow(E,b*(o + s))) + pow(E,a*o + (a + b)*s)*(-2 + 2*pow(E,b*o) - b*o) + d1*pow(E,a*s)*(-pow(E,b*o) + pow(E,a*o)*(1 + b*o)) + pow(d,2)*pow(E,a*s)*(-pow(E,b*o) + pow(E,b*(o + s)) + pow(E,a*o)*(-1 + pow(E,b*s) - b*s)) +  d*(-(d1*pow(E,b*(o + s))) + (1 + d1)*pow(E,b*o + a*s) - pow(E,a*s + b*(o + s)) + pow(E,b*s + a*(o + s))*(1 + b*o) + pow(E,a*(o + s))*(-1 - b*o + b*d1*s)))))......;
```

res2 will also be of this kind, and in the end I need to calculate res1/res2, which usually becomes a very small number.

I was thinking of splitting the formulas and adding terms to mpg_z in order to not get out of double range for each term, but as the formulas are so long and complex, that this is almost impossible.

So in summary, the problem is, that my intermediate results can get so huge that no data type is capable of storing them, so I cannot assign it to mpz and get rid of this problem.

I am aware that I want to calculate a double value and actually use mpz_t for integers. As far as I understand this is the only way to store such big data, since mpf_t can only handle float type. To be honest, there is still confusion on my side about the representation in `gmp`.

Any ideas how to approach this ?

Comment: Consider using all mpz_t variables.  Lose the integers variables (which are promoted to doubles in the part of your code that I can see),  you gain nothing by using them anyway.  Make everything mpz_t from the very start of your function.  BTW what are you trying to do?

Comment: It looks like you're not doing integer arithmetic, so I'd stick with mpf_t and implement your whole formula using the floating arithmetic provided by gmp.

Comment: This is theoretical population genetics and I am trying to calculate  moments of inter-coaescent times given an arbitrary demographic piecewise function

Comment: The above comments are still correct. If you want to use GMP for parts of your algorithm, it is far easier to just use GMP for ALL of your algorithm. GMP is actually not that much slower than native integers, in my experience. Also, if you really are doing floating-point math, might I reccommend MPFR (http://www.mpfr.org/) instead of GMP.

Comment: You might want to use the C++ interfaces, to avoid creating arbitrary temporary variables for pieces of your formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1** Long double allows to handle larger numbers than double (both in the exponent and in the significand precision). But you have to think that your 1e308 order of magnitude doesn't mean anything if your goal is to store large integers; you only have to care about the size of the significand precisions, either 52/53 bits (double) or 64 bits (x86 extended precision). If you try to use it with larger integers, you will have a correct order of magnitude but the exact value will be lost (when computing with integer numbers, people generally care a little more about this than when playing with approximate numbers).

**Question 2** Using GMP is a nice choice. Other libraries also exist; for smaller values I use a lot the [libqd](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/) which has an extended fixed precision and are *very quick* but this will not be enough for your own problem. Now your question is about setting the values:

- using a string version of the number is generally a bad idea (you should keep that only for input/output purposes); it is a slow operation involving basis conversions and digit by digit treatment
- doing as much as you can with the GMP types is the way to go (unless you really care about speed and have a full control over the expected range for the values to be computed with native types
- if your formula is too long, I can't help much. But using GMP isn't that difficult, can't you really convert your formula? is there some logic in your formula that you could embed in a loop? maybe you could write a quick and dirty python script for converting your formula to a piece of C code using GMP?

Now I don't fully understand why you want to use `mpz_t` rather than `mpf_t`. This type implements arbitrary long floating numbers; did you notice you can set the precision with `mpf_set_default_prec`?